# Unity Admob onRewarded gives me Wrong Amount

Tags: c#, admob, unity-game-engine

I working with an Admob API from Github -> https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob

Im facing a strange problem. My Script works! I start ShowRewardVideo() on button click and it shows me the video. Afterwards i want to gift Coins to my User. As you can see it just increases the current Amount of Coins in PlayerPrefs by adding 20.

Where the problem is? I dont get +20 Coins i geta random amount of coins extra. Last time it was +280 and +320 before that. I tested it with other amounts and it seems like i always get the reward multiple times. So 14 * 20 = 280 and so on.

But why ismy script adding the reward multiple times?

Can you please help me?

```
private void Start() {
Admob.Instance().rewardedVideoEventHandler += onRewardedVideoEvent;
```

}

```
    public void ShowRewardVideo() {
    if(Admob.Instance().isRewardedVideoReady()) {
        Admob.Instance().showRewardedVideo();
    } else {
        Admob.Instance().loadRewardedVideo("ca-app-pub-5129395190259237/xxxxxxxxx");
        ShowRewardVideo();
    }
}

void onRewardedVideoEvent(string eventName, string msg) {
    Debug.Log("handler onRewardedVideoEvent---" + eventName + "   " + msg);
    if(eventName == "onRewarded") {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("mmig", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("mmig") + 20);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all check how often this part of your code gets called:

```
if(eventName == "onRewarded") {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("mmig", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("mmig") + 20);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Do this simply make a Debug.Log("Runned") call or something similar. 
Also you should maybe consider to do this part:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("mmig", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("mmig") + 20);
```

With something like this:

```
int oldAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("mmig");
int newAmount = oldAmount + 20;
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("mmig",newAmount);
```

To avoid possible implicit covertig errors. But this change it not necessary for your current problem, just a tip :).

Just make sure to check how many times you get the output above in your console

Comment: Thank you very much but i cant check the console because its only working in the build version on android.

Comment: Oh okay.. you could also increase a variable and then display the variable on a text element of the canvas. So basicly count up (++) the variable every time the method gets called. After that you set text value of a text element or gui text (old unity system) to the variable.